# Design Approach: Android Restful with JSON

Tags: android, json, web-services, design-patterns, rest

I am developing a parking system, where the mobile device queries parking data from the server database. In other words the user requests for an empty parking spot and the server sends him a free spot number on his device. I'm using a restful architecture with JSON.

I watched the Google I/0 2010 rest client applications video, and he explained that you could use 3 design patterns:

1. Service API
2. contentprovider API
3. contentprovider & syncadapter

I can't decide which of these 3 will be the best fit for my application, does anybody have any useful hints/knowledge?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented a solution using the suggestions from that Google I/O session, and it has worked out really well for me.

For retrieving data from a remote server, a background thread is a must since you can't block the UI thread while waiting on the server to respond. The easiest way to do that is with an AsyncTask that gets the data from the server in `doInBackground` and then does whatever UI updates or saving of data that needs to happen in `onPostExecute`. This approach will work well enough for a lot of use cases, but the problem that the Google I/O session was addressing was that you will lose data if your Activity is interrupted while waiting on the server to respond. The solutions proposed in that session were suggestions for ways to save the data so that it can be stored in a way that isn't attached to an Activity.

Using a Service you can separate the data retrieval from an Activity. (Keep in mind though that you will still need to create a separate thread in the Service to retrieve the data since a Service still runs on the UI thread.) The ContentProvider comes into play when passing the information from the Service to the Activity that requested the server data. You can use a database to store the response. Then the Activity can get the response from the database.

The SyncAdapter can be used to retry failed server calls and/or get data from the server without the app specifically requesting so it will be fresh and ready when the app needs it. Of course, that should really be used very sparingly since it could drain the battery quite a bit.

I would highly recommend at least going with the Service/ContentProvider approach. I was able to use that solution to easily integrate a caching mechanism into my app as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you provide an example implementation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to share any of the actual code from the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Service for sure. What I'm assuming you want is a semi constant update that informs the user of the open spot and changes if the spot is jacked. A service is best suited for running in the background waiting for the JSON data you send it.

A ContentProvider and SyncAdapter I believe only handle data on the phone, so I'm not sure why you would want to use those.

Comment: ok i'm starting to understand now. I understood the google video wrongly then, I thought they all could be used for all data and not only data on the phone. Do you by any chance have any suggested books/ resources about this topic? 

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The docs are always a good resource. I always have at least two docs related tabs open. Other than that, both of the books I have purchased are absolute garbage. I just use the docs, google and stack. With that I can find what ever I need.